# Tkinter how to popout a Toplevel window by cursor movement instead of button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code in which when I click the button, the function is called and a window pops up. What I want is, when I click tab and move from the first entry box to the second entry box, I need this function to be called. My intention is to eliminate the need for the "Click" button.

```
from Tkinter import *

def fn_jump():
    window3 = Toplevel()
    window3.title("This window popped out")
    secondentry = Entry(window3)
    secondentry.grid(row=0)
    secondentry.focus_set()

root = Tk()
txtbox1 = Entry(root)
txtbox2 = Entry(root)

txtbox1.grid(row=0)
txtbox2.grid(row=1)
txtbox2.focus_force=fn_jump   #This does not work

btn1 = Button(root, text = 'Click' , command=fn_jump)
btn1.grid(row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `bind` to run a function when the Entry gets focus.

```
txtbox2.bind('<FocusIn>', fn_jump)
```

To use bind, the function you are calling must accept an event argument, so change that definition to

```
def fn_jump(event=None):
```

Comment: Thanks, this works however there is a weird problem. When I close the popped out window it keeps creating another new one. This is happening in a loop and I need to close the root window in order to close the child window.

Comment: That's what you wanted: every time it gets focus it makes the popup. Design your function to put the focus elsewhere or add a check or something. Without knowing what your goal with this project is I can't help you further with that.

Comment: `txtbox2.bind('<KeyRelease>', fn_jump)`
This works as expected. The problem was because when I close the child window, the cursor was automatically going back to the txtbox2 so the child window was created over and over again. I will accept your answer.